# solve apache problem when more clients connect the site

Tags: php, ajax, oracle, apache, smarty

I have a php web application on web server connect with two oracle db server in loadbalance between them... we use in web application smarty template engine ..and ajax jquery 
the problem in
- when more clients connect the web application the site stop or apache not running so we make restart to apache.
- some web pages is slow.

i want to fix the problem and how to make apache more performance with more clients.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give a lot of details, so some (general) possibilities:

1. Using PHP opcode caching. See: APC, xcache, Zed
2. Use a separate static media server for all static media.
3. Play with MaxChildren/MaxClients and the related options.
4. It's possible you are simply getting too many visitors. Upgrade to a faster machine, or load balance between multiple app servers.